# regarding sparse tensor representation

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

In the context of sparse tensor representation of Tensorflow, the [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/sparse_ops/sparse_tensor_representation) gives the following definition and corresponding example. I can see why `shape=[3,4]`, but I am not very clear why `indices=[[0, 0], [1, 2]]` and `values=[1, 2]`. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually use sparse vector/matrix/tensor when one value is way (way) more represented than the other one. Usually, this value is zero, as you see in the example.

Now, the trick is to consider that tensor's values are 0 by default, then to specify which elements are not 0.

You can consider `indices` as coordinates in an `ndims` space, and `values` the corresponding values.

- **Dense Tensor Philosophy**: "create a tensor like: `[[1, 0,0,0],[0,0,2,0],[0,0,0,0]]`"
- **Sparse Tensor Philosophy**:

  - "create a zero valued tensor having a [3,4] shape
  - put `1` (=`values[0]`) at `[0,0]` (=`indices[0]`)
  - then put `2` (=`values[1]`) at `[1,2]` (=`indices[1]`).

For example, if you want to add a 3 a the bottom-right corner, you must set `indices=[[0,0],[1,2],[2, 4]]`, `values=[1,2,3]`.

Got it?
Hope it helps